# spring mvc; contextConfigLocation load order

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm reconfiguring a webapp. I want to move everything out of dispatcher servlet into ContextLoaderListener. (This is due to changes in security configuration beyond the scope of this question)

**Question 1,** if I have multiple application context xml files, does it matter what order they are loaded? For example does the xml file containing context:component-scan need to be loaded before the xml file specifying DAO and service beans?

**Question 2,** (or is this moot?) how would I specify the order in which *_applicationContext.xml are loaded assuming that A_applicationContext.xml should be loaded before B_applicationContext.xml which should be loaded before C_applicationContext.xml

My web.xml is as follows:

```html
    <web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
       xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
       http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

       <servlet>
          <servlet-name>AssessmentDelivery</servlet-name>
          <servlet-class>
             org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
          </servlet-class>
          <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
       </servlet>
     
       <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>AssessmentDelivery</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <context-param>
         <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
         <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/*_applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- security filter -->
    <filter>
      <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
     </filter>

     <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
     </filter-mapping>

     <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
     
    </web-app>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some suggestions:

For these days consider do the configuration for Spring through Javaconfig.

To answer questions 1 and 2 is very important you understand the following:

- When you run the app Spring creates an `Application Context` where exists all the beans created and managed by Spring. Now consider that for that `Application Context` it should be created from two 'sub' applications contexts, normally they are 'mentioned' in the documentation how `ServletApplicationContext` and `RootApplicationContext`

  - The former should scan all about the Web, such as your `@Controller`s and `@Bean`'s about infrastructure such as for `ViewResolver` etc..
  - The later should scan all about the Server, such as `@Service` and `@Repositories` and `@Bean`'s about infrastructure such as for a `DataSource` etc.

Is very important understand the following:

- `ServletApplicationContext` --> `RootApplicationContext`

  - It means the former can get access the latter (it about use dependencies i.e: a `@Controller` needs a `@Service`). Therefore it reflects that the `Web` side can access the `server` side.

Once said this the following is **not** possible

- `RootApplicationContext` --> `ServletApplicationContext`

  - has no sense that a Bean from the server side want access the web side (a bad practice)

Long time ago I don't use `web.xml` but

- `DispatcherServlet` + `contextConfigLocation` (through `<init-param>`) represents the `ServletApplicationContext`
- `ContextLoaderListener` + `contextConfigLocation` (through `<context-param>`) represents the `RootApplicationContext`

It does not matter if the beans are declared through:

- `XML`
- `JavaConfig`
- annotations `@Controller` etc.

Spring manages the cycle about in what order the beans are created. So do not matter how the `.xml` files (in your case) are declared (about the order).